# STM32F767 flash programming issue

Tags: stm32, hal, flash-memory, mcu

We are trying to program the MCU flash memory to write and save some data on it.
After a single write to a single sector(that might have failed), when we try to write/overwrite the same sector we fail.
We are using HAL_FLASHEx_Erase to delete the sector.
In particular, we use the ideas in this article https://controllerstech.com/flash-programming-in-stm32/

Looking for advice on how to proceed from here/ things to think about that we might have missed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Your question is very vague. "Nothing works pls help". Please, post your code, indicate what works and what doesn't, after what line things go wrong.

Comment: Also, you can always check if write worked by reading back from there?